# the resulting value is outside the range for the data type decimal/numeric(31/31)

Tags: sql, derby

I have a complex sql which has more than 1000 row so I can't paste it here. I am using derby in memory db. When ı run my sql I get this error : the resulting value is outside the range for the data type decimal/numeric(31/31).

How can I fix it? any idea?

Comment: Have you tried narrowing it down at all, to a specific part of the query?  The range for `NUMERIC/DECIMAL` data type is –10^38+1 to 10^38–1, so you may have some very large number that is outside the range.  If you could post the suspected SQL then it may be easier to provide assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a truncate function... really your trouble is that your decimals are more that your precision.. for example.. if you hace a decimal (10,2) it means that you can hace until 2 decimals... (counting for your 10 in numbers), you cant use 123456789.123 beacause your number of digits are mor than decimal (10,2)... if you need more info you can visit this link. [Link info decimal sql server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187746.aspx)

Comment: how can I set decimal (X,Y) in sql?

Comment: you can use CAST or CONVERT to do this... [link] http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: I used CAST function where the value is out of range and I fixed problem! THX my friend